# How to split a matrix market file according to the number of rows of the matrix stored in it?

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I would like to split a market matrix file into two parts. These two parts should be of varying sizes. Such sizes should be corresponding to the number of rows of the matrix represented by the hash in the market format.

There are some examples:
http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html

For a usual matrix file format of , e.g., 100 rows it is quite easy:

```
head -n 70 matrix1.mtx > matrix170.mtx

tail -n 30 matrix1.mtx > matrix130.mtx
```

where in `matrix170.mtx` there are the 70 first lines of `matrix1.mtx` and so on.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

You can use this script to split the matrix file unevenly

```
awk -v splits='70 30' 'BEGIN{n=split(splits,s);i=1;limit=s[i]}
                       NR==1{split(FILENAME,f,".")}
                            {if(NR<=limit) suffix=s[i];
                             else limit+=s[++i]}
                         i>n{exit}
                            {print > f[1] suffix "." f[2]}' matrix.mtx
```

will generate two files `matrix70.mtx` and `matrix30.mtx` derived from input file name and split values.